# OL3 with custom projection (Proj4) and wmts

Tags: openlayers, proj, wmts

I have a problem with projection in ol3.
I want to integrate a wmts layer with projection: EPSG:25832 (UTM 32) using Proj4.

I tried to combine the ol3 wmts example : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html
with a previous question here: [Openlayers3 using custom EPSG:25832](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171770/openlayers3-using-custom-epsg25832?newreg=8c60c6209ed945bd9b393a1b4b66747b).

At the moment this is my code:

```
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.12/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  var myProjectionName = 'EPSG:25832';
  proj4.defs(myProjectionName, "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");
  var projection = ol.proj.get(myProjectionName);
  var projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
  var size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
  var resolutions = new Array(14);
  var matrixIds = new Array(14);
  for (var z = 0; z < 14; ++z) {
    resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
    matrixIds[z] = z;
  }
</script>
```

When i run my learning script i get followed error:

```
TypeError: projection is null  ol3.html:19:1
```

meaning this line:

```
resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
```

What have I done wrong?