# OpenLayers - WFS Projection not showing EPSG:25832

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I can't solve the display of my WFS.
I can see the request returning the data in my debugger, but it is not showing.
My reference for solving this problem was [Openlayers3 using custom EPSG:25832](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171770/openlayers3-using-custom-epsg25832).

Am I right, suspecting that I do not need to further transform my vectorLayer?
Is my center causing the problem, because I transform to 'EPSG:3857' rather then 'EPSG:25832' (again I would suspect not - since it is just the center)?

```
let myProjectionName = 'EPSG:25832';
proj4.defs(myProjectionName, '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs');
let myProjection = ol.proj.get(myProjectionName);
this.mapView = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.transform([9.98, 53.55], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
  zoom: 9,
  projection: myProjection
});

let vectorLayer = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GML(),
  url: function(extent) {
    return 'https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WFS_Statistik_Stadtteile_Wahlergebnisse' +
      '?version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=Statistik_Stadtteile_Wahlergebnisse:Buergerschaftswahl_15.02.2015_-_Wahlbeteiligung_in_Prozent' +
      '&bbox' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:25832';
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
  projection: 'EPSG:25832'
});

this.map = new ol.Map({
  target: this.mapId2,
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorLayer
    })
  ],
  view: this.mapView
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple problem was the (maybe Angular 5 specific) initiation and usage of proj4.

ol.proj.get was not receiving the new declaration of proj4.defs(myProjectionName, ...) because it had to be set separately afterwards!

```
let myProjectionName = 'EPSG:25832';
proj4.defs(myProjectionName, '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.setProj4(proj4);

let myProjection = ol.proj.get(myProjectionName);
myProjection.setExtent([239323.44497533192, 4294418.796805557, 760676.5550246682, 9320086.206906328]);
```

Now ol.proj.get(myProjectionName) is not returning NULL and allowing my View to transform and the WFS to map properly.

Helpful references: [ol.proj](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.html)  and [PROJ4JS Doku](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js)

Answer (score 0):

I've identified some issues in your code to display the layer

- the center should use the `EPSG:25832` projection (you were aware of it from your post)
- an extent for the projection  should be set (recommendation, not an obligation). It will clip other layers (calculating reprojection outside the valid extent of the projection could go wrong)
- projection can't be set in the `ol.source.Vector` but instead at layer level e.g `ol.layer.Vector`
- projection should be also set in the OSM layer as you need to explicitly tell OpenLayers to get raster tiles from EPSG 3857 and reproject them
- `ol.format.GML` has to be `ol.format.WFS`

I've also use a public proxy to avoid CORS issue (https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com)

You will find below the corrections and you can browse [a working demo](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/7be91afe37fd07d42c7f94116a95b536)
Be cautious, it will take seconds to display the vector layer. It's probably related to WFS size and maybe proxy speed too (didn't investigate...)

```
  let myProjectionName = 'EPSG:25832';
  proj4.defs(myProjectionName, '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs');
  var myProjection = ol.proj.get(myProjectionName);
  myProjection.setExtent([239323.44497533192, 4294418.796805557, 760676.5550246682, 9320086.206906328]);

  var mapView = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([9.98, 53.55], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25832'),
    zoom: 9,
    projection: 'EPSG:25832'
  });

  var vectorLayer = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.WFS(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WFS_Statistik_Stadtteile_Wahlergebnisse' +
        '?version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=Statistik_Stadtteile_Wahlergebnisse:Buergerschaftswahl_15.02.2015_-_Wahlbeteiligung_in_Prozent' +
        '&bbox' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:25832';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
  });

  let map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        projection: 'EPSG:25832'
      }),
      new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorLayer,
        projection: 'EPSG:25832'
      })
    ],
    view: this.mapView
  });
```

Comment: thanks so much for your effort. the loading time is due to the size of the data - not heroku. just a small comment: you didn't use 'setExtend' on your working demo - or at least its not in the code.
there are two problems that i still encounter:
1. ol.View({ center: does not work with ''EPSG:25832'' (Error: Cannot read property 'wb' of null : ol.js 36). if I switch to my initial 3857, at least the background-map is showing
2. (that might be the root of the problem) I can't setExtend because ol.proj.get(myProjectionName) is NULL

Comment: I've aligned both example and above code. Issues where related to using `let` extensively instead of `var`. (example tested)